# Nice and simple IDE recommendation (and hint on which one this may be)?

Tags: ide

I would like to try out a simpler IDE for my projects that does not come with all the bells and whistles VS or PyCharm comes with but that I can customize so I get the complexity I need.

I've been looking around trying to find a nice and simple one and came accross this image, however I cannot find what its name is.

[image]

Comment: It might help if you'd specify 1) what kind of projects/languages you're working with, 2) which tasks the IDE should support, 3) on what OS it should run and 4) how much you'd be willing to spend when it comes to paid software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio Code is what you're looking for.

Comment: Welcome Shindouuu!  Your answers are getting flagged by our community as low quality.  Please expand your answers to include *why* and *how* the software you are recommending meets the requirements presented by the OP.  Please also provide links to whatever software you recommend.  Thanks!